# Adobe Certified Expert-Adobe Commerce Cloud Developer code

Tags: magento2.4, magento-enterprise, magento2-cloud, magento-cloud

Can anyone tell me the exam code for Adobe Certified Expert-Adobe Commerce Cloud Developer?

Seems like the this one is changed
**AD0-E706 Adobe Commerce Cloud Developer Expert**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, Adobe has retired that cloud certification and just has an "Expert Developer with Cloud Add-on" https://express.adobe.com/page/gHMvWEByL74qK/

They still have text for the Expert Cloud in the Solution Partner Portal but the link 404's and my certification for that one has no renewal path available.

[image]